# Windows Azure Bill

Tags: azure

I want a PDF of the Bill generated against Windows Azure Subscriptions, I selected View Bill and then went to Billing History. Clicking on the download link it shows usage details but not the Invoice. Can anybody please suggest where to get Invoice in PDF form?

Comment: VTC. This isn't a programming question, and would be better asked on Azure support forums. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/windowsazureplatform,azuremarketplace,windowsazureplatformctp

Comment: @Deepesh While this isn't an appropriate question for here and it was appropriately closed, you can get PDFs by going to Billing History.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to see you invoice in PDF format you have to

1. Go to your [subscriptions screen](https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions)
2. Go to particular subscription screen
3. Go to Billing History screen for the selected subscription

On the *billing history* you will see billing periods, amount you paid, link to download usage in the given period and link to download invoice for the given period.

[image: Billing History]

You can see example Billing History screen of my *Storage Pay-As-You-Go* subscription.

I hope that will help.

Comment: yup. total shambles. still no ability to get invoices emailed to accounts department automatically.

Comment: Took my 10 minutes to find this information, I find the portal horrendous from a user point of view, and very slow to load each and every screen.